# Python Regex Capture

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file that has the data:

```
B4-B9   4
B1-B3   8
B5-B6   1
B7  4
B8 - B9 5
B12-B19 6
B17 - B24 3
B22, B23 3
B24-B29 8
B30,B31 10
B32-B39 12
B45-B47 12
B48-B49 15
B50 14
B17, B18 18
B41,B42 19
```

I would like to capture each letter 'B' with a number in each line in a group and a third group containing the number without a B.

I made the regex `(B\d+)*\s*-*,*(B\d+)+\s(\d+)` but I am having trouble capturing in the instances where there are spaces between the dashes or commas.

```
B8 - B9 5
B17 - B24 3
B22, B23 3
B17, B18 18
```

Comment: Would you please try : `(B\d+)(?:\s*[-,]\s*(B\d+))?\s+(\d+)`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this regex to capture each `B` value and the final number into a dictionary (or tuples of values):

```
(?P<b1>B\d+)\s*(?:[-,]\s*(?P<b2>B\d+))?\s+(?P<num>\d+)
```

It looks for:

- a `B` with some number of digits (`(?P<b1>B\d+)`), captured in group `b1`;
- an optional `-` or `,` followed by another `B` with some number of digits (`(?:[-,]\s*(?P<b2>B\d+))?`, with the `B` value captured in group `b2`; and finally
- some number of digits (`(?P<num>\d+)`) (captured in group `num`)

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6Oyc5Z/1)

In python (assuming each line is in the variable `s`):

```py
m = re.match(r'(?P<b1>B\d+)\s*(?:[-,]\s*(?P<b2>B\d+))?\s+(?P<num>\d+)$', s)
if m is not None:
    print(m.groupdict())
```

Output (for your sample data):

```py
{'b1': 'B4', 'b2': 'B9', 'num': '4'}
{'b1': 'B1', 'b2': 'B3', 'num': '8'}
{'b1': 'B5', 'b2': 'B6', 'num': '1'}
{'b1': 'B7', 'b2': None, 'num': '4'}
{'b1': 'B8', 'b2': 'B9', 'num': '5'}
{'b1': 'B12', 'b2': 'B19', 'num': '6'}
{'b1': 'B17', 'b2': 'B24', 'num': '3'}
{'b1': 'B22', 'b2': 'B23', 'num': '3'}
{'b1': 'B24', 'b2': 'B29', 'num': '8'}
{'b1': 'B30', 'b2': 'B31', 'num': '10'}
{'b1': 'B32', 'b2': 'B39', 'num': '12'}
{'b1': 'B45', 'b2': 'B47', 'num': '12'}
{'b1': 'B48', 'b2': 'B49', 'num': '15'}
{'b1': 'B50', 'b2': None, 'num': '14'}
{'b1': 'B17', 'b2': 'B18', 'num': '18'}
{'b1': 'B41', 'b2': 'B42', 'num': '19'}
```

If you would prefer just tuples of data, change `groupdict` to `groups` i.e. `m.groups()`, then the output will be:

```py
('B4', 'B9', '4')
('B1', 'B3', '8')
('B5', 'B6', '1')
('B7', None, '4')
('B8', 'B9', '5')
('B12', 'B19', '6')
('B17', 'B24', '3')
('B22', 'B23', '3')
('B24', 'B29', '8')
('B30', 'B31', '10')
('B32', 'B39', '12')
('B45', 'B47', '12')
('B48', 'B49', '15')
('B50', None, '14')
('B17', 'B18', '18')
('B41', 'B42', '19')
```